# python function return none value instead of integer

Tags: python, function

```
def g(n):
    s = 0
    while n >= 1:
        s = s + n % 10
        n = n // 10

    if s // 10 == 0:
        return s
    else:
        g(s)


n = 0

while n != -1:
    n = int(input())
    print(g(n))
```

the sum up a integer until it reaches to a 1 digit number .
for example
n= 29

2+9=11

1+1=2

so the function should return 2 . but it return "None" .
Can anyone please help me where the wrong is ?

Comment: You probably meant: `return g(s)` in the last function line.

Comment: its call the function itself when the number is not a one digit number. by the updated sum value of the current integer n .

Comment: Calling the function (itself) is one thing. Returning a result is another. You need to return the recursive call result, otherwise the function will return (by default)  *None* (even if it computed the correct result)

Comment: Thank you  . we should return the value which we got from the recursive call otherwise it will return none .  return g(s)

Comment: Added a small improvement so that the program ends when user inputs ***-1***.

Comment: @MaskurAlShalSabil Just as an explanation; the recursive call `g(s)` will evaluate `2` but does not do anything with it. It is like writing the integer literal `2` on that line instead. So you need to return it.

Comment: (Note that it works the same way that it would if you called *any other function*. Simply calling it does not cause anything to be returned.)